# Not able to make a button change color ONLY while clicked (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I want a button to change color when it's pressed, then change back to its original color when its released. Currently I have a button that takes you to a fragment when pressed. I tried simply using

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

in the button's onClickListener but realised that when it took me to the fragment and I returned to the activity, the button is still the same color and hasn't changed back. So my plan of action is to change it's color when its pressed, launch the fragment, then set the button's color to how it originally was so that if I press back the button appears to be as normal (unclicked).

However, I cannot seem to find an example online that shows me to GET the color of a button as an int (so I can use setBackgroundColor(int)). Any ideas?

Highly grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should use selector for this purpose -

create selector.xml (in res/drawable) folder:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_bg_normal"></item>
```

`

and set selector as backround to button:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:background="@drawable/selector"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="126dp"
 android:text="Hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change the background colour, just use a selector.create an xml file in the drawable folder(give it a name i.e colour_change). the selector has several state. just as in the code below, the first part(default) show that a button is not pressed and focus, that will be the colour. the second part show when a button is focus and not pressed while the third part shows when a button is both press and focus. 
when you press a button it changes to the colour specify the moment it is realeased it returns to the default colour state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


 <!-- default -->
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape >
        <solid  android:color="#CD853F" />
     </shape>
</item>

<!-- button focused -->
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true">
    <shape >
    <solid
            android:color="#00ff00" />
     </shape>
</item>
<!-- button pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape >
        <solid
            android:color="#00ff00" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

the XML for the button is

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/press_button"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:layout_width="fiil_parent"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:text="Press me" />
```